# Why does the printf fail to print Jack and George's names?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printf

I would like to know why Jack and George's names fail to print. I tried adding another member in the struct the names get printed normally, why is that ? I would really appreciate it if someone can help. Here's the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef unsigned short int u16;
    typedef unsigned char u8;
    typedef struct 
    {
     u8 name[10];
     u16 salary;
     u16 bonus;
     u16 deduction;
     //u8 x;//why does the printed name get ruined 
     //without this?
     }employee;
     void main (void)
     {
       employee arr[3]={{.name = "John"},{.name = 
        "Jack"},{.name = "George"}};
       u16 i = 0;
       u16 sum = 0; 
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("\nPlease enter %s's Salary:",arr[i].name);
    scanf(" %d",&arr[i].salary);
    printf("\nPlease enter %s's Bonus:",arr[i].name);
    scanf(" %d",&arr[i].bonus);
    printf("\nPlease enter %s's Deduction:",arr[i].name);
    scanf(" %d",&arr[i].deduction);
    sum = sum + arr[i].salary + arr[i].bonus - arr[i].deduction;
}
    printf("\nTotal value needed is: %d",sum);
}
```

Comment: but you're showing the code that _works_ right? can you show what changes you made exactly / or the code which _doesn't_ work?

Comment: You are using the wrong format specifier in `scanf` which leads to memory corruption. An easy fix is to change to reading an `int` instead of "u16" (which you shouldn't be definiing yourself anyway since the language already provides fixed width types)

Comment: turn all warnings on (see MM comment)

Comment: @M.M which format specifier should I use instead of %d then?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the code doesn't work with " u8 x" commented

Comment: `%hu` would be correct in this case. But I would recommend reading into an `int` and then assigning that back to your struct field.

Comment: [What is the format specifier for unsigned short int?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8699812)

Comment: @Nemo, `%d` will read into `int`. `%hu` is closest you get to `u16`, but its not guaranteed.

Comment: If it is a memory corruption, then changing the 'shape' of the memory (like by adding more fields or variables on the stack, for example) sometimes causes the corruption to happen on a part of the memory that is not used, or that is used for something else (causing either no symptoms, or a different symptom)

Comment: @M.M I thought that the memory widths sometimes differ from a compiler to another e.g sometimes int is 2 bytes and other times it's 4 bytes isn't this true ?

Comment: @Nemo `%hu` is defined as the specifier for reading `unsigned short` regardless of sizes, which is what the code has (it defines u16 as typedef for unsigned short)

Comment: @M.M I tried '%hu' and it works fine thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how do I turn the warnings on ? I am using a gcc compiler.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your scanf()'s are wrong, and are overwriting members of your struct.

A decent compiler will issue a lot of warnings that are very severe:

```
$ gcc -Wall t.c
t.c:13:11: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
      void main (void)
           ^~~~
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:22:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘u16 *’ {aka ‘short unsigned int *’} [-Wformat=]
     scanf(" %d",&arr[i].salary);
             ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             %hd
t.c:24:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘u16 *’ {aka ‘short unsigned int *’} [-Wformat=]
     scanf(" %d",&arr[i].bonus);
             ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             %hd
t.c:26:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘u16 *’ {aka ‘short unsigned int *’} [-Wformat=]
     scanf(" %d",&arr[i].deduction);
             ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             %hd
```

When you are calling `scanf(" %d",&arr[i].salary);` , the `%d` says to store the number you read as an int type.

However you have declared `salary` as a `u16` type, which on your system is probably a lot smaller than an `int`. `scanf` jsut assumes you were telling the truth when you provided `%d` ,and stores an int in whatever the `&arr[i].salary` pointer points to, overwriting memory after that variable which might overwrite and trash the `name` array.

So either

- declare your `salary, bonus and deduction` as `int` instead of `u16`, so it matches the `%d` argument you give to `scanf`
  or
- Provide a proper type specifier to `scanf` for your `u16` variables, which is `%hu`.

e.g.

```
   scanf(" %hu",&arr[i].salary);
   scanf(" %hu",&arr[i].bonus);
   scanf(" %hu",&arr[i].deduction);
```